# Java generic method wildcard mismatch issue

Tags: java, generics

The basic thing I want to achieve is to map a list of references `List<Ref<Thing>>` to a list of the actual objects, but given by the superclass `List<SuperThing>`. In this example, `Thing extends SuperThing` and `Ref<Thing>` has a method `public Thing get()` to get the referenced object.

The method that I assumed valid:

```
public <T> List<T> refsToObjects(List<Ref<? extends T>> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Ref<? extends T> ref : list) {
        result.add(ref.get());
    }
    return result;
}
```

But when I try to use it

```
List<Ref<Thing>> refs;
List<SuperThing> objectList = refsToObjects(refs);
```

I get this error message: `The method refsToObjects(List<Ref<? extends T>>) is not applicable for the arguments (List<Ref<Thing>>)`

I did not actively use the `? extends T` wildcard structure before, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, if you specify the "extended" parameter also as generic parameter:

```
    public <T, S extends T> List<T> refsToObjects(List<Ref<S>> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Ref<S> ref : list) {
        result.add(ref.get());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 At first I thought taking `List<? extends Ref<? extends T>>` would be enough, but that still doesn't seem to work without explicitly calling `this.<SuperThing>refsToObjects(refs)`.

Comment: I don't like declaring an extra type variable that is only used in one place in the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your method as taking `List<? extends Ref<? extends T>>` instead:

```
public <T> List<T> refsToObjects(List<? extends Ref<? extends T>> list) { ... }
```

Nothing should have to change within the body.

**EDIT:** type inference still seems to fail at the call site using this solution. It only works with a call like `this.<SuperThing>refsToObjects(refs)`. So [wrm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14136559/697449) using an additional type parameter is preferable if you can expect this kind of usage.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see it, there are two errors in your code.  The first is to believe that the type `List<Ref<? extends Thing>>` is a supertype for `List<Ref<Thing>>`.  If we create a subclass of `Thing` like `DerivedThing`, we cannot add an instance of `Ref<DerivedThing>` to a list of `List<Ref<Thing>>`:

```
List<Ref<Thing>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<Thing>>();
refs.add(new Ref<Thing>()); // OK.
refs.add(new Ref<DerivedThing>()); // Error!
```

However, if we replace this with `List<Ref<? extends Thing>>` then there is no more problem with the class `DerivedThing`:

```
List<Ref<? extends Thing>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<? extends Thing>>();
refs.add(new Ref<Thing>()); // Still OK.
refs.add(new Ref<DerivedThing>()); // Now OK!
```

Therefore, if the compilator was to allow to pass of a value of `List<Ref<? extends Thing>>` to a function taking `List<Ref<? extends Thing>>` as its argument, this would allow the function to add some invalid item to the list.

The second error is to think that the base type (or erasure type) of `<? extends Thing>` is `SuperThing` instead of remaining `Thing`. Here, `<? extends Thing>` designates the collection of type composed of `Thing` and its derived classes and not the collection of `SuperThing` and its derived classes.  Therefore, we could write:

```
List<Ref<? extends Thing>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<? extends Thing>>();
refs.add(new Ref<Thing>());
List<Thing> objectList = refsToObjects(refs);
```

or, with `SuperThing` as the erasure type:

```
List<Ref<? extends SuperThing>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<? extends SuperThing>>();
refs.add(new Ref<Thing>());
List<SuperThing> objectList = refsToObjects(refs);
```

but not a combination of both because `List<SuperThing>` is not a superclass for `List<Thing>.`  Notice that we can stil add a `Ref<Thing>` to a `List<Ref<? extends SuperThing>>`.  Therefore, use of one of the above solution or use the [wrm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14136559/697449) if you want to keep `List<Ref<Thing>>` as your starting point.

Personally, I would prefer to use polymorphism at its fullest extend and always reference everything from a `SuperThing`; even when creating `Thing` or `Ref<Thing>` objects.  For example, if we add a parameter of type `T` to the constructor of `Ref()`:

```
List<Ref<SuperThing>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<SuperThing>>();
refs.add(new Ref<SuperThing>(new Thing()));
List<SuperThing> objectList = refsToObjects(refs);
```

Note that we are now passing an object of type `Thing` to a reference of type `SuperThing` in the constructor of `Ref()`.  By using the superclass of the hierarchy as the reference for all the derived objects, all the coding become much more simpler. OOP works very well and very easily when you choose to see all the objects mostly only through their superclass and this extends to the use of generic.

Answer (score 0):

The types must match exactly, so:

```
List<Ref<? extends Thing>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<? extends Thing>>();
List<SuperThing> objectList = refsToObjects(refs);
```

should work.

Comment: Do you mean `? extends SuperThing` there?

Comment: Although this solution might work, I preferred to keep the ugly generic parts in the method rather than in my main code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I still get "incompatible types" at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

It will also work if you do something like this:

```
List<Ref<Thing>> refs;
List<SuperThing> objectList = this.<Thing>refsToObjects(refs);
```

What is happening is that the method expects something which extends `T`. but you never define `T`. The one explained by @wrm defines it in the method.